# AWS S3 bucket restrict accss

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'd like to set up a website on S3 bucket. The website is for our team admin to submit a list of student names so that those names could be stored in the database.

Now if I'd like all team members are able to view the website, but only allow one person(team admin) to really submit the names, what should I do? I think this is access permission issue, but not quite clear how AWS deal with this. I guess related to IAM users/roles? But exactly what should I do?

Many thanks

================

Forget to mention, my design involves the whole chain like S3/static website, Javascript, Lambda function, API Gateway, DynamoDB. I'm wondering at which step and how should I control the access?

Another thinking is, should I create an account for team admin, so that only he could login and submit? Maybe not necessary?

Answer (score 1):

S3 Websites are static. This means that you cannot execute code to do anything, such as query a database.

To implement your objective, you will need to combine several services.

S3 Websites: Your S3 bucket will store all of the files such as CSS, JavaScript, HTML, Images, ...

JavaScript: When the client accesses your website, JavaScript functions will be loaded with your HTML to provide client based processing.

Amazon Cognito: Cognito will manage authentication. Using STS your clients will receive temporary access keys to access AWS resources.

DynamoDB: This will be your database. Using the access keys from Cognito / STS, users will access the database. The level of access is controlled by your AWS IAM Policies that you created for each user or group of users.

There are lots of examples of this design on the Internet and several "serverless" books have been written with entire designs mapped out.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Surely I have design for all of those you mentioned. Then in order to only allow admin to fill in the form, submit, and store in database, at which step should I control the access? From your words I guess at the DynamoDB step using Amazon-Cognito?

Comment: Yes, using IAM Policies that Cognito and STS use to assign permissions. For example, for users that only need to read the database (DynamoDB), the IAM Policy denies write permissions and only allow read. For the admin, grant all required rights.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use IAM roles to provide read/write access to the DB. (short answer)

S3 is only good for hosting your static website, whereas if you wish to restrict read and write controls - I would suggest you switch to either AWS RDS instance or AWS Aurora.

With RDS, you can have a read replica - which will only give read access to viewing users and only you as an admin can insert/update the tables.

This solution would also make your DB's response time better.Since the reads would be handled by different instance and writing by different.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks! So I'm guessing, suppose I restrict DB access only to admin, so when someone else tries to fill in form and submit, it simply won't work and pop out errors?

Comment: You would limit which pages are displayed based upon a token (session state) that you set as part of the authentication process. This is not actual authorization of pages, just branch logic to display the correct type of page, or display a page that says "You don't have permission" type of page.

Comment: If you follow my solution of having read replica, the users won't have write access. Simply means they have 'read-only' access and not write.
In the case of simple DB restriction using IAM roles - the IAM would block them from altering the table.

Comment: Yes, but I'm kind of inclined to DynamoDB because we are dealing with very little information...So relational database like RDS is kind of waste？

Comment: @KartikChadha - be careful with designs that will cause errors. This can have the side effect of lots of customer support or the impression of poor quality. Some of this logic can be implemented in Lambda so that dynamic HTML can be generated on the fly. This way the user never gets a page that will generate an error.

Comment: Yup, if your dataset is small. Probably punching in a JSON to a Dynamo DB would be ideal. Visit IAM service once if you wish to implement the same, that's easy and convenient service for permission control.